# What Exactly happens when an object is serialized

Tags: c#

HI 
when an object (having sub objects) is serialized using a BinaryFormatter, what exactly happens? how the object data is stored? how the strings used to map the objects store? I want to know the serialized stream format.
please help me ..

Comment: Maybe you should accept some answers on the other serialization questions you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reverse-engineered description [here](http://primates.ximian.com/~lluis/dist/binary_serialization_format.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There is content I have read in Java head first:
Objects on the heap have state—
the value of the object’s instance
variables. These values make one
instance of a class different from
another instance of the same class.

Serialized objects save the values
of the instance variables, so that
an identical instance (object) can be
brought back to life on the heap